# Undefined reference in libpangoft2

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, pango

Recently I've installed `GTK+ 3.22` and its dependencies:

- `GLib 2.50`
- `Pango 1.40`
- `Gdk-Pixbuf 2.36`
- `Atk 2.22`
- `GObject-Introspection 1.50`

The installation was successful because I tried using some new features of `GTK+ 3.22` in one of my Python projects and it worked. (Before the installation, if I tried using a new feature, Python would raise an exception)

I am also working on a game which is written in `C++` and I'm using `Cocos2d-x` to create it. Before installing the above libraries, everything worked fine. After the new packages were installed, I built my game in `CodeBlocks` and the following error message was shown:

`In file: /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 undefined reference to 'pango_matrix_get_font_scale_factors'`

After some research, I've found out from [here](https://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/changelog/pango/1.40.0/log.html) that in `Pango 1.37` the `pango_matrix_get_font_scale_factors` function was added which is exactly the function that my project cannot find. As mentioned above, I've installed `Pango 1.40` as a requirement for `GTK +3.22`.

I've also tried installing `libpangoft2-1.0-0` with `apt-get install` and the output was: `libpangoft2-1.0-0 is already the newest version.`

Out of curiosity I've also looked in `/usr/local/lib` to see if I can find the `libpangoft2-1.0-0` library.
In `/usr/local/lib` I've ran the following command: `ls -la | grep pango` which gave me the following output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff      1095 Oct 30 14:08 libpango-1.0.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   staff        24 Oct 30 14:08 libpango-1.0.so ->  libpango-1.0.so.0.4000.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   staff        24 Oct 30 14:08 libpango-1.0.so.0 -> libpango-1.0.so.0.4000.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff   1073136 Oct 30 14:08 libpango-1.0.so.0.4000.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff      1263 Oct 30 14:08 libpangocairo-1.0.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   staff        29 Oct 30 14:08 libpangocairo-1.0.so -> libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.4000.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   staff        29 Oct 30 14:08 libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 -> libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.4000.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff    216216 Oct 30 14:08 libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.4000.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff      1209 Oct 30 14:08 libpangoft2-1.0.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   staff        27 Oct 30 14:08 libpangoft2-1.0.so -> libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.4000.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   staff        27 Oct 30 14:08 libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 -> libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.4000.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff    397496 Oct 30 14:08 libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.4000.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff      1265 Oct 30 14:08 libpangoxft-1.0.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   staff        27 Oct 30 14:08 libpangoxft-1.0.so -> libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.4000.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   staff        27 Oct 30 14:08 libpangoxft-1.0.so.0 -> libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.4000.3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff    157240 Oct 30 14:08 libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.4000.3
```

I tried reinstalling `Pango 1.40`, but the `undefined reference` error still persists.

I would also like to mention:

- I am using Debian 8
- Since installing `GTK+ 3.22` my Nautilus looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekgeH.png), notice how I do not have icons (only some kind of replacement) next to the **Close** button and next to my HDDs (note that the black rectangles were added by me)
- I am using i3 as a window manager

My question is, how can I solve the `In file: /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 undefined reference to 'pango_matrix_get_font_scale_factors'` error?

**Update**

If I uninstall `Pango 1.40` I do not get the error anymore, but `GTK+ 3.22` will not work.

**Update2**

Maybe `Pango 1.40.3` is not installed correctly. I described an interesting problem I am having [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320108/installing-pango-1-40-3).

Comment: Did you replace your system GTK+ with the new one? Installing to a local prefix should not have overwritten your icons, and I am starting to wonder if your system is corrupt. In any event, does `pango_matrix_get_font_scale_factors()` show up if you run `nm /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0`?

Comment: @andlabs if I run `gtk3-demo --version` it outputs `gtk3-demo 3.22.2`, but `dpkg -l libgtk-3-0` outputs `libgtk-3-0:amd64          3.14.5-1+deb8u1`. Regarding the 2nd question, `nm /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 | grep matrix` outputs a few functions and `U pango_matrix_get_font_scale_factors` is one of them.

Comment: What does `which gtk3-demo` say? And `dpkg-query -L libpangoft2-1.0-0 | grep libpangoft2-1.0.so.0`?

Comment: @andlabs `/usr/local/bin/gtk3-demo` and for the dpkg command `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.3600.8  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0` and also take a look [here] (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320108/installing-pango-1-40-3) I am describing something strange about `Pango 1.40` which might help